# Multiplication within SQL statements?

Tags: php, sql, syntax, multiplication

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY (votes * id) DESC');
```

This gives me an error. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So.... do we get to guess what the error was? And what type is votes?

Comment: most likelt a problem with types, please give the table definition and error message

Comment: as a side note, you should avoid using select * in code, if somebody adds a column your code will break!

Comment: This query works fine for my version of SQL.  What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, (votes * id) AS x FROM submissions ORDER BY x DESC
```

You will have one column more but i guess i will work =|

Answer (score 1):

I guest you want to get the list of submissions order by vote numbers and ids.
you may use the code like this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY votes DESC, id DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you gave is valid as long as the types are correct. At least in Postgres. What database are you using?